# Populating an empty table with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, html-table

I am trying to "search" for an item by making a GET request to my service and then populate my table with the response but I cannot seem to achieve that with my code.

```
$(function(){
 var $searchInput = $("#search");
 $("#searchOptions").change(function(){
 if($(this).val() =="Fragment"){
 $searchInput.keyup(function(e){
 var q = $searchInput.val();
 $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://localhost:51834/CoffeeService.svc/getaorderfrag/' + q,

    success: function(orders){
    $("#orderTable").empty();
    $.each(orders, function(i, order){
        $("#orderTable tbody").append('<tr><td>' + order.Name + '</td><td>' + order.Order + '</td><td>' + order.Price + '</td></tr>');
         });
        }        
      });
    });
   }
 });
});
```

Comment: *"I cannot seem to achieve that"* - Care to elaborate?

Comment: @jbutler483 When the items have been gotten, the table disappears and it's just an empty space.

Comment: Check your network in your inspect element to see if anything is returned from the server

Comment: @jbutler483  I made a console.log for the success and the items do arrive.

Comment: the `.empty()` method would clear the table completely, you're then looking to select a child element (`tbody`) that wouldn't be there. Try `$("#orderTable tbody").empty();`

Comment: @jbutler483 That helped but the problem with it is that it's an "instant search" and the table has to be emptied everytime the user changes the value.

Comment: [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69317/css-shapes-and-designs)

Answer (score 0):

jbutler483 is right, you are killing the entire table, thead, tbody, (everything) with your $("#orderTable").empty(); statement.

Your append is targeting something that doesn't exist.  Try this:

```js
$(function(){
 var $searchInput = $("#search");
 $("#searchOptions").change(function(){
 if($(this).val() =="Fragment"){
 $searchInput.keyup(function(e){
 var q = $searchInput.val();
 $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://localhost:51834/CoffeeService.svc/getaorderfrag/' + q,

    success: function(orders){
    $("#orderTable tbody").empty();
    $.each(orders, function(i, order){
        $("#orderTable tbody").append('<tr><td>' + order.Name + '</td><td>' + order.Order + '</td><td>' + order.Price + '</td></tr>');
         });
        }        
      });
    });
   }
 });
});
```